# Pandas multiplot line graph looks wrong

Tags: python, pandas

So my code opens up a data file, this has 3 columns of data and is quite long. Using pandas, It looks like:

```
               V     n             I
0       0.001350   1.0  2.905273e-06
1       0.002850   1.0  3.131104e-06
2       0.004350   1.0  3.378296e-06
3       0.005850   1.0  3.555298e-06
4       0.007350   1.0  3.833008e-06
...          ...   ...           ...
100103  0.173451  83.0 -7.324219e-09
100104  0.133451  83.0  3.662109e-09
100105  0.093451  83.0  7.324219e-09
100106  0.053451  83.0  9.765625e-09
100107  0.013451  83.0 -1.770020e-08

[100108 rows x 3 columns]
```

Now using n as an identifier I can seperate them and plot them altogether on a graph. I use :

```
#open data file and read in data:
#data location
f =r'C:\Users\Z\Desktop\Projects\PHD\1st\ML\BurnMLScripts-master\data\Test Char\chip1\D8_12\_burn\000456_CE_16_burn_d20.dat'

#store data using pandas
data = pd.read_csv( f, sep = '\t', comment = '#', names = ['V','n','I'] )

#observe data format
print(data)

#plot data
fig=plt.figure
data= data.pivot(index = 'V', columns = 'n', values = 'I')
data.plot.line()
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

The resulting graph doesn't look like the line graph I intended, the shapes their but not the actual point to point line. The data points do loop back across the x domain once they hit a max point, I imagine thats the problem but I need the full trace without the lines being drawn from the bottom section up to the top, the space in between them should be empty.

[image: weird line structure]

Any ideas on how I can correct this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, I assume that you want a categorical line plot, with `V` variable on x axis, `I` variable on y axis, and a separate line for each `n` value.

I would suggest to use seaborn plotting library.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Then you load your data...

data["n"] = data["n"].astype("category")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.lineplot(data=df, x="V", y="I", hue="n", ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

As you can see, there is no need to pivot the DataFrame.

Notice the need to set column `n` to categorical dtype, so that `sns.lineplot` will treat `n` as different categories, and not as a continuous number.
In general, i strongly recommend Seaborn for this kind of visualizations!

Comment: Wow that fixed a problem I was having with a different data set, sadly the graph it produces is near identical. Taking a closer look at the graph its drawing lines from the loop back up to the forward moving sets of the data, any idea how to stop that?

Comment: @sleepy
If that's the case, it probably means that your data actually has that shape!
For instance, if you plot this data:
`x = [1, 2, 3, 1]`, `y = [5, 6, 7, 8]`
It is expected that the lines loop back, since `x` values are not always increasing: there will be a loop between the first and the last point.
For this kind of data, a scatterplot may be more appropriate than a lineplot.
I suggest `sns.scatterplot` (just change that in my example), and let me know if it works for you!